# SVN to Gitlab migration using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, svn, gitlab

Our organization just moved from SVN to GitLab, and every team has been instructed to move their code themselves from svn to gitlab. My team has 18-19 projects with a lot of folders/subfolders in every svn project.

Is there any way I can do it through Python, as both svn and Gitlab have python API's? Any lead in this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need python to do this as this operation can be done using only `git` commands. Git official website is providing documentation on how to perform a migration from `SVN` to `Git` [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git). I used it once to migrate `SVN` projects to `GitLab` and it worked well.